# Find the celestial body

Tags: cipher, outer-space

[image]

*Last week, a group of 5 astronauts went on a space-tour. They accidentally got crashed on a celestial body in space. Luckily no one was harmed! They were amazed to see some highly intelligent aliens there. The aliens helped them to fix their space shuttle and return safely to Earth. The Chief Astronaut saw the following
note on the celestial body.*

[image]

## ***Can you find out where they crashed?***

HINT 1

> Telescope

HINT 2

> Fantastic Four

HINT 3

> ebg - abezny (k3)

HINT 4

> Asteroid belt

HINT 5

> Somehow related to this.[image]

Edit: Code is split now

Comment: It's been somewhat of a while now, may we have another hint?